# C# (visual studio 2019). Dynamically created object by clicking a button. The object have to be created in another usercontrol.cs

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I am new in c# and eager to learn but I have a huge problem.
So basically I am trying to create an app which creates objects by clicking a button.
This is how I would like it to look:

```
####################################################################################
     Form1.cs [project]                                                            #                                                                                                                                 
___________________________________________________________________________________#
                                                         Usercontrol1.cs[Project]  #
    #########################################                                      #
    #        Usercontrol2.cs[project]       #           O-checkbox-Item1           #
    #    ____________________________      S#           O-checkbox-Item2           #
    #    |                          |      C#           O-checkbox-Item3           #
    #    | 5 apples    "close bttn" |      R#           O-checkbox-Item4           #
    #    |__________________________|      O#           _________________          #
    #    ____________________________      L#           |Amount up/down |          #
    #    |                          |      L#           |_______________|          #
    #    | 2 oranges   "close bttn" |      B#       _____________________________  #
    #    |__________________________|      A#       | Add to shopping list bttn |  #
    #                                      R#       |___________________________|  #
    #########################################                                      #
                                                                                   #
####################################################################################
```

The app should work and look like this (an example)
Im in shop and I'd like to buy 5 apple, 2 oranges etc. so I'm choosing an item by checking the box near the items name and setting up the amount and then I'm finnaly clicking add to the shopping list button. After then the labels should appear like below:

The problem appears when the shopping list will become very long so it will be near or will exceed the area I want it to be.

So I'm seeking a solution in which:

1. I can create "boxes" with products on shoplist dynamically.
2. I can close the ones I dont need anymore, for example when I changed my mind and I don wont apples any more so I click close button which is "in" the box(or should I say on the box).
3. The "case" in which the boxes will be created is scrollable so in case there are a lot of positions, the shopping list wont exceed certain area.

I don't know how to start dealing with this problem, so any help will be apreciated. The question is is it even possible like this?
If creating objects inside a usercontrol.cs  from another user control is not possible my question is - Is there any other way of dealing witch such problem?

EDIT:
For now I know how to dynamically create an objects.

Comment: You're actually asking several different, very broad questions here ... SUGGESTIONS: 1) Take a look at the [ListView](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/working-with-listview-in-C-Sharp/) control.  See how far you can go with it  2) [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle): try to do as much as you can with the "standard controls": buttons, labels, edit boxes, groups, checkboxes, radio buttons and comboxes

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to show the following items:

- a combo box with all available products; the operator selects a product that he wants to order
- a numberic updown that shows the amount he wants to order
- A button Add, used to indicate that the operator finished selecting the product and the amount. Clicking the button will result in an Order line
- A datagridview that looks like a table showing all orderLines.
- A button delete to remove all selected OrderLines
- A button to clear the complete Order
- A button to indicate that the Order is complete.

It is easier if you add all these items using the visual studio designer.

Code will be like this:

```
class Product
{
    public int ProductId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
}

class OrderLine
{
    public Product Product {get; set;}

    public string Name => this.Product.Name
    public int Amount {get; set;}
    public decimal ProductPrice => this.Product.Price;
    public decimal Total => this.Amount * this.ProductPrice;
}
```

ComboBoxes and DataGridViews both show sequences of similar items. They have a property `DataSource`. This is a sequence that holds the items that should be displayed.

A ComboBox doesn't display the complete item; it has a string property `DisplayMember`. This contains the name of the property of which the value should be displayed.

```
ComboBox comboProducst = new ComboBox()
{
    DisplayMember = nameof(Product.Name),
};
```

You want that the ComboBox displays the Names of all products. In your class you need a collection of Products that must be displayed. I assume that this collection doesn't change while the program runs, otherwise you get in trouble if suddenly a Product is removed.

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<Product> AvailableProducts {get;} = ...
```

In the constructor:

```
public myForm()
{
    this.InitializeComponents();
    // will create the items added using the designer

    // ComboProducts shows the names of all AvailableProducts:
    this.ComboProducts.DataSource = this.AvailableProducts;
}
```

And bingo! your combo box shows the names of all available products.

The operator can select a product and an amount, and press the Add button. Of course if nothing is selected, or the amount is not positive this button should be disabled.

```
bool OrderLineOk => this.ComboProducts.SelectedIndexe >= 0
                 && this.NumericUpdownAmount.Value >= 0;

void OnComboProductSelectionChanged(object sender, ...)
{
    this.ButtonAdd.Enabled = this.OrderLineOk;
}

void OnSelectedAmountChanged(object sender, ...)
{
    this.ButtonAdd.Enabled = this.OrderLineOk;
}
```

Again: use the visual studio designer to subscribe to these events.

Now, if the operator selected a Product and a positive Amount, the Add button Enables. If this button is pressed:

```
void OnAddButtonClicked(object sender, ...)
{
    Product selectedProduct = (Product)this.ComboBoxProducts.SelectedValue;
    int amount = (int)this.numericUpdownAmount.Value;
    this.AddOrderLine(selectedProduct, amount)
}
```

I do this in a separate procedure, to be able to Add OrderLines on a different way, for instance, using a menu.

The OrderLines will be kept in an ObservableCollection. Whenever this Changes, all controls that show this ObservableCollection will automatically reflect the changes.

```
ObservableCollection<OrderLine> OrderLines {get; } = new ObservableCollection<OrderLine>();

void AddOrderLine(Product product, int amount)
{
    OrderLine orderLine = new OrderLine
    {
        Product = product,
        Amount = amount,
    };
    this.OrderLines.Add(orderLine);
}
```

Now we need to display the OrderLines in a DataGridView. Use the designer to create the DataGridView and add the columns. Similar to a Combobox, every Column has a property that says which property should be displayed: `DataPropertyName`.

Code will be like this:

```
DataGridView dgv1 = new DataGridView();
DataGridViewColumn columnDescription = new DataGridViewColumn
{
    HeaderText = "Description",
    DataPropertyName = nameof(OrderLine.Description),
    ValueType = typeof(string),
    ...
};
DataGridViewColumn columnAmount = new DataGridViewColumn
{
    HeaderText = "Amount",
    DataPropertyName = nameof(OrderLine.Amount),
    ValueType = typeof(int),
    ...
}
DataGridViewColumn columnProductPrice = new DataGridViewColumn
{
    HeaderText = "Price per item",
    DataPropertyName = nameof(OrderLine.ProductPrice),
    ValueType = typeof(decimal),
    ...
}
DataGridViewColumn columnTotal = new DataGridViewColumn
{
    HeaderText = "Total",
    DataPropertyName = nameof(OrderLine.Total),
    ValueType = typeof(decimal),
    ...
}

// add the columns
dgv1.Columns.Add(columnDescription);
dgv1.Columns.Add(columnAmount);
// etc.
```

In the constructor you can tell the DataGridView that it should display Orderlines:

```
public myForm()
{
    this.InitializeComponents();
    // will create the items added using the designer

    this.ComboProducts.DataSource = this.AvailableProducts;
    this.dgv1.DataSource = this.OrderLines;
}
```

And bingo: your DataGridView shows the elements in the Order. Pity, your Order is empty yet, but you already have the code to add OrderLines.

```
void OnButtonClear(object sender, ...)
{
    this.OrderLines.Clear();
    // because it is an ObservableCollection, dgv1 is automatically updated
}
void OnButtonRemove(object sender, ...)
{
   this.RemoveSelectedOrderLines();
}

void RemoveSelectedOrderLines()
{
    // TODO: messageBox to ask operator if removing the selected items is ok
    DialogResult dlgResult = MessageBox(...)
    if (dlgResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var selectedOrderLines = this.dgv1.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Select(row => (OrderLine)row.DataboundItem);

        this.dgv1.SuspendLayout(); // no updates while removing orderlines
        foreach (var orderLine in selectedOrderLines)
        {
            this.OrderLines.RemoveItem(orderLine);
        }
        this.dgv1.ResumeLayout();
```

The button `Complete Order` should only be enabled if there are OrderLines:

```
bool CanCompleteOrder => this.OrderLines.Any();

void UpdateButtonCompleteOrder()
{
    this.ButtonCompleteOrder.Enabled = this.CanCompleteOrder;
}
```

Call this method whenever the OrderLines change.

```
void OnButtonCompleteOrderClicked(object sender, ...)
{
    // no need to read the dgv. OrderLines is already up to date
    this.CompleteOrder(this.OrderLines);
}
```

### Allow to Edit the DataGridView

Instead of a separate ComboBox / Amount / Add button, you could allow editing in the datagridview directly. Make the columns all columns except Amount read-only.

Instead of binding the ObservableCollection to the DataGridView, make an intermediate class that is assigned to the DataGridView:

```
BindingSource sourceDataGridView = new BindingSource()
{
    AllowEdit = true,
    AllowNew = true,
    AllowRemove = true,
    DataSource = this.OrderLines,
}

this.dgv1.DataSource = sourceDataGridView;
this.dbv1.AddingNew += AddingNewOrderLine;

void AddingNewOrderLine(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
{
    // Display a dialog box with a ComboBox with products and Amount
    using (var dlg = new DialogAddProduct())
    {
        dlg.AvailableProducts = this.AvailableProducts;
        var dlgResult = dlg.Show(this);
        if (dlgResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            OrderLine orderLine = new OrderLine
            {
                Product = dlg.Product,
                Amount = dlg.Amount,
            }
            e.NewObject = orderLine;
        }
    }
}
```

A third possibility is to add a ComboBoxColumn to the datagridview, but that costs a lot of time to explain.
void AddNewOrderLine()
{